# Generating a variable table from inputted values

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have a starting angle (34.905943), end angle (120.7377) and radius (8274.4). I want to make a graph using VBA that takes the starting angle, have VBA add a number to make the cell underneath it 35 (essentially have the rounded up value in the cell below), and for each cell under 35, add 0.1, until 120.7, and take the difference to make the end angle of 120.7377..... an example of the desired output table below:

34.905943 
 35 
 35.1 
 35.2
 .
.
.
120.6
120.7
120.7377

```
Sub Starting_Angle()

Range("A6").Copy 'This is calculated via the x and y coordinates in A3 and B3 respectively using =DEGREES(ATAN(A3/B3)) [the staring angle]
Range("A14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ' insert the starting angle


Range("A12") = (Range("B9") - Range("A9")) / 0.1 ' find the number of iterations of angle +0.1 that are needed

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Range("A12")

If Range(Cells(i + 14, 1)) < Range("B9") Then

Range("Q1").Copy
Range("A14", Cells(i + 15, 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd
Continue
Next
End If


End Sub
```

I also have been able to round the values outside of the VBA using ceiling and then subtracting to get the difference and then adding that to get the desired value of 35. However if I could bother you to make that in VBA that would be super!

My code is probably not very good because I'm still a beginner at this... I apologize in advance.

P.S, I'm not too sure how to word the question, so if there is already a post that you know of that answers this question please leave me a link, instead a bunch of down votes :)

Thanks,
Jake

Comment: Just to understand, can you go over what values you have in what cells? Where are you storing the values 34.905, 120.7377, etc that your macro will use. Also, do you want to keep storing all the extras, or you just want your data outputted to range A14 down? Please explain more....

Comment: Hi @JohnBustos, the initial values are stored as follows: top x,y A3,B3 respectively, Bottom: x,y D3,E3 respectively. Starting angle A6, ending angle D6. Ceiling of start angle A9, difference between the two, A10, start of the table A14

Comment: ...... the values stored in A3 and B3: 4733.7, 6784.1 respectively. D3 and E3: 4096.3, -6888.6 respectively

Comment: So, put simply, you want A14 = A6; A15 to round A14 up to the nearest 0.1 (unless A14 is already a multiple of 0.1); keep growing down column A by 0.1 till you reach the number <= D6; Last value = D6. Correct?

Comment: Yes @JohnBustos that is exactly it :)

Comment: Ok... Let me see what can be done...

Comment: Sounds good! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do this with a loop - Excel is perfect for this already if you just play around with some of your formulas. In VBA, your code would look as follows (commented to explain each step):

```
Sub Starting_Angle()

    ' Insert starting angle into A14:
    Range("A14").Formula = "=A6"

    ' Round A14 up to the nearest 0.1, but also take into account that the starting angle may already be a multiple of 0.1:
    Range("A15").Formula = "=IF(A14 <> CEILING(A14,0.1),MIN(CEILING(A14,0.1),$D$6),A14+0.1)"

    ' Add 0.1 to each corresponding cell below until you reach the value in cell D6, then, the last value needs to equal D6. After that, just leave blanks:
    Range("A16:A10000").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(R[-1]C=R6C4,"""",MIN(R[-1]C+0.1,R6C4)),"""")"

    ' Convert all the formulas into values:
    Range("A14:A10000").Value = Range("A14:A10000").Value

End Sub
```

Note that my middle formula uses `R1C1` notation. That just makes it easy to refer to the cell above each cell. To see what it looks like in normal excel, put a break point right after that line, then look at your excel sheet. Or, otherwise, just comment out the line that converts the formulas into values.

Hope that helps / does the trick!

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad it worked - I edited some of my comments to try and explain more of the "why" - Hope it helps with your general understanding too.

Comment: What if the angle goes from 270 to 22.19527? I need something that will go until 359.9, go to 0, then go until 22.19529. I made this to loop it back to 0, however it doesn't stop at 22.19527... it keeps going until it hits 2000 cells Range("K16:K2000").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(R[-1]C=359.9,""0"",MIN(R[-1]C+0.1,359.9)),""0"")"

Comment: The easiest way to deal with that would be to add in a "helper column" that normalizes the angles to grow above 360 if needed (using the first simple check of `D6`<`A6` and, if so, to simply add 360 to `D6` for your end angle), then do all the calculations as normal and then use a formula around the lines of `Mod(XX,360)` to keep bringing the numbers back down to angles <360 ... Does that make sense?

Comment: But, even that doesn't solve the solution of more than a full revolution occurring... You have to be more specific with your question / criteria to see how complex you want to go